# Material-ui How to toggle Menu component clicking IconButton

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I use IconButton instead of Button, the onClick is having an error saying that Type '(event: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322).

```
    <div>
      <Button aria-controls="simple-menu" aria-haspopup="true" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> try calling it by calling a function within your components click which returns your method event from placeholder like this

`{() => handleClick()}`

Comment: Having an error - Type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322)

Comment: please pass that event to your props if you have not passed it yet.
handleClick: () => Event